# Auto checkin a directory of Git

Tags: git

I realize there are very good reasons I should not be doing this. However, given that I'm stupid, what is the best way to do the following.

I am using a directory in my git repo basically as a key value store. Where the filename is the key, and the value is the contents of the file.

I want, on every `git commit`, for files in this directory to be automatically added into the repo.

How should I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to *git add* the directory everytime you do a commit? You can use git hooks for that, take a look at [Customizing Git - Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), *pre-commit* hook more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want something like [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/), it lets you use a Git repository for filesharing and automaticly synchronizes your repository folder :)